# WordPress Woocommerce + GravityForms (my-orders - дополнительные ячейки)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Задача - вывести дополнительные ячейки в последних заказах, в личном профиле пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php

Формируются данные в данном шаблоне.

Вся трудность в создании верного запроса. Необходимо получить данные именно "variation" товара и вывести на страницу.

В "variation", через GravityForms, заполняются дополнительные данные, по виду: "год", "организация".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо же, пробовать получить данные через запрос напрямую к GravityForms (вероятно, это не будет верным решением).

Comment: Через jQuery решение замечаю - get/load к странице и вывод данных, но как через PHP - не удаётся понять.